# HTML link does not open in target frame

Tags: javascript, html, frameset

Recently I have been asked for help with a set of HTML pages, that failed to work as expected. The setup consisted of a frameset, where links shown in some frame should open in some other frame. This should be accomplished by the target attribute on the anchor element, or a base element with a target attribute in the page containing the link.

The problem was that links did not open in the desired target frame, but in a different tab.

After some analysis, I found out that this behavior was caused by the presence of a Javascript variable "name", which was present on the page that was initially loaded in the target frame. If the value of that variable did not match the name of the target frame, the link opened on a new tab. In case it matched the target frame name, the link opened in the target frame, as expected.

This happens consistently in recent versions of at least three browsers (tried Firefox, Chrome, and Edge).

I would like to know why it works this way.

Here is a small reproduction of the issue (also available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40560tukf2leukm/html.zip)), with a frameset, three frames with initial content, and two links. The first link, with `target="two"`, opens in frame "two". But the second link, with `target="three"`, does not open in frame "three", instead it opens in a new tab. Apparently this depends on the value of Javascript variable "name" in the initial content of that frame, three.html. But why?

**index.html**:

```html
<html>
  <frameset rows="33%,33%,*">
    <frame name="one"   src="one.html">
    <frame name="two"   src="two.html">
    <frame name="three" src="three.html">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

**one.html**:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    frame "one"
    <br>
    <a target="two" href="content.html">show content (target="two")</a>
    <br>
    <a target="three" href="content.html">show content (target="three")</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**two.html**:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    frame "two"
    <script>
      <!--
      var name = "two";
      //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**three.html**:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    frame "three"
    <script>
      <!--
      var name = "two";
      //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**content.html**:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see you specified `var name= "two"` in both html pages. Maybe that's the error.

Comment: @MarkSkayff that's exactly what I am asking. Why does the target frame depend on the value of variable `name` in the initial content of the desired frame? Please explain why you think this is an error.

Comment: For what you are saying here I think that the properties of the the Frame object become globals on the page that is being loaded in the frame. Thus you can control and modify those globals within the script itself.

Comment: Let me try to replicate this in my environment.

Comment: Note that [the `<frame>` element has been obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for many years, as has `<frameset>`, and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that by setting the variable `name` in the pages, you are overriding the `Window.name` variable.

And that `Window.name` variable is what the system uses to determine the Frame's name. When you override this value and change it, and then try to reach the frame with the older value, then you are redirected to a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

HTML file when targeted with link name specified in the frame tag does not open in that named frame. The problem is the frame where it is loaded is calling the other frame to load a new html file does not recognise the name or it can't find where the named frame as specified in the frameset orderly as per syntax. There is no mistake in naming the calling frame. The link opens in itself in its own frame where the html document is calling. It means it opens in the same window frame as _SELF is being executed. The calling frame  with its HTML file and primararily the code the anchor tag  can't see the window frame I am calling to load the desired HTML file and can't recognise the name I have given to the calling frame.

How to solve.....the first para problem. ?
I reiterate there is nothing wrong in the browser. I have the best app browser line-ups. All execute work fine with all web pages.

Ross

Comment: is this a new question? If so please post a different question, don't add on as an answer